# filter out ip address log file with string character

Tags: java, regex, string

This is a portion of my log file extracted out by my java program but I will not interested with this portion of log

```
2017-05-30 23:11:33,673 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking logout agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=STEDGE/172.16.8.3]
2017-05-30 23:11:33,682 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Logout agent success [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=STEDGE/172.16.8.3]
2017-05-30 23:11:33,819 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.KeyboardInteractiveAuthentication - SSH: Sent SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_INFO_REQUEST (Password Authentication): 
2017-05-30 23:11:33,871 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - User login attempt has been made from address /172.16.8.1:54626
2017-05-30 23:11:32,042 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking config agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]
2017-05-30 23:11:32,072 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Config agent success [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]
2017-05-30 23:11:31,072 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking config agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]
2017-05-30 23:11:31,090 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Config agent success [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]
2017-05-30 23:11:31,091 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking auth agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=STEDGE/172.16.8.3]
2017-05-30 23:11:31,095 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - SSH: Failed login attempt on [172.16.8.1]. Username: "rene1".
2017-05-30 23:11:18,673 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking logout agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=STEDGE/172.16.8.3]
2017-05-30 23:11:18,682 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Logout agent success [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=STEDGE/172.16.8.3]
2017-05-30 23:11:15,819 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.KeyboardInteractiveAuthentication - SSH: Sent SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_INFO_REQUEST (Password Authentication): 
2017-05-30 23:11:15,871 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - User login attempt has been made from address /172.16.8.1:54626
2017-05-30 23:11:14,042 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking config agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]
2017-05-30 23:11:14,072 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Config agent success [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]
2017-05-30 23:11:12,072 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking config agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]
2017-05-30 23:11:11,090 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Config agent success [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]
2017-05-30 23:11:10,091 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking auth agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=STEDGE/172.16.8.3]
2017-05-30 23:11:09,095 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - SSH: Failed login attempt on [172.16.8.1]. Username: "rene1".
```

I want the IP in these lines of log only

```
2017-05-30 23:11:32,072 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking config agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]
2017-05-30 23:11:32,072 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Config agent success [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]
2017-05-30 23:11:31,072 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking config agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]
2017-05-30 23:11:31,090 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Config agent success [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]
```

what I can think out is using regular expression for filter out the IP in these line, only one IP is sufficient for me because the IP address is belong to end user IP address. So, I had set up my own pattern for the regular expression but it's not works as expected. The following is my pattern

```
(?<=accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/)[\\d.]+
```

[This](https://regex101.com/) is the testing website where I play along with my pattern, anyone here able to advise the most suitable pattern to filter out my desired result?

Comment: are those line by line in a list of strings???

Comment: `List<String> listOfLines = getLogAsListOfStrings();
listOfLines.stream().map(v -> v.substring(v.lastIndexOf("/"), v.length - 2)).forEach(v -> saveIp(v));` lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can put those log messages in a list

and filter using a Predicate

example:

```
List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("172.16.8.3",
            "Invoking logout agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=STEDGE/255.16.8.3]",
            "2017-05-30 23:11:33,673 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking logout agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=STEDGE/172.16.8.3]",
            "2017-05-30 23:11:33,682 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Logout agent success [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=STEDGE/172.16.8.3]",
            "2017-05-30 23:11:33,819 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.KeyboardInteractiveAuthentication - SSH: Sent SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_INFO_REQUEST (Password Authentication): ",
            "2017-05-30 23:11:33,871 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - User login attempt has been made from address /172.16.8.1:54626",
            "2017-05-30 23:11:32,042 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking config agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]",
            "2017-05-30 23:11:32,072 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Config agent success [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]",
            "2017-05-30 23:11:31,072 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking config agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]",
            "2017-05-30 23:11:31,090 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Config agent success [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]",
            "2017-05-30 23:11:31,091 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking auth agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=STEDGE/172.16.8.3]",
            "2017-05-30 23:11:31,095 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - SSH: Failed login attempt on [172.16.8.1]. Username: \"rene1\".",
            "2017-05-30 23:11:18,673 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking logout agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=STEDGE/172.16.8.3]");
    
Predicate<String> predicate = t -> {
        return t.indexOf("remoteAddress=gateway") != -1;
};
List<String> myFilteredList = myList.stream().filter(predicate).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(myFilteredList);
```

---

## edit:

to get only the ip address use an UnaryOperator

```
UnaryOperator<String> operator = t -> {
String ipPatt = "(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(ipPatt );
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(t);
if (matcher.find()) {
    return matcher.group();
} else {
    return "0.0.0.0";
}

};
    List<String> myFilteredList = myList.stream().filter(predicate).collect(Collectors.toList());
    myFilteredList.replaceAll(operator);
```

final output:

> [172.16.8.1, 172.16.8.1, 172.16.8.1, 172.16.8.1]

Comment: thanks for the code, where is the "t" variable? do it need to declare ? I had to import the Predicate library ?

Comment: but my printed filtered list show me empty, this is my updated source code using your solution(http://codepad.org/7RAT6qnk)

Comment: I found out myList is empty

Comment: it's show me another error now "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at test1.main(test1.java:75)
"

Comment: almost done! :) but do List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>(); instead of List<String> myList = null;.... you will get a nullpointerexception

Comment: Good,it can run properly but it's not return the filtered result which contain IP address only.

Comment: I only want the IP address in the log right after remoteAddress=gateway/, I been struggling on this issue few hour ago

Comment: thanks for ur sharing about the knowledge and experience because it's let me learn new things. It's work now. Have a nice day

Comment: if it works and you find the answer helpful then please Up-Vote and accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

How about doing it like this ?

```
    String str = "2017-05-30 23:11:32,072 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking config agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]";
    String pat = "remoteAddress=gateway/";
    int index = str.indexOf(pat);
    if(index != -1) {
        System.out.println(str.substring(index + pat.length(), str.length() - 1));
    }
```

Try this :

```
BufferedReader br3 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p3.getInputStream()));
    String line3;
    while((line3 = br3.readLine()) != null)
    {
      //  System.out.println(line3);  
      str2 = line3;
      String pat2 = "remoteAddress=gateway/";
      int index1 = str2.indexOf(pat2);
      if(index1 != -1)
      {
        System.out.println(str2.substring(index1+pat2.length(),str2.length()-1));
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it's not working, please refer to this link for the error I got(http://codepad.org/sToxvfOt). FYI, this is portion of my code(http://codepad.org/g3xaRsZf)

Comment: I am getting this error (Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -22
), able to advise ?

Comment: @yumi If the pattern is not present in string it will return -1 as index, so i just added the condition to check that. It should work now !

Comment: hi sumit, it's doesn't print out anything in the print statement, please refer to this link(http://codepad.org/sFVUCJRx) for my updated code, let me know if you want to see full program

Comment: @yumi I just saw your code and seems like you need to move the code into while loop since you are simply skipping all the lines and only last line is getting processed.

Comment: I will try out your solution as well so I can get another option also, thanks for ur help for the others site of this world